# Transmit data from one text box to another using mscomm control

Tags: vb6

I want to send data from one text box to another and I wrote the code as below... there is no error but I don't receive any data

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Dim inp As String
    Dim oup As String
    inp = Text1.Text
    MSComm1.Output = inp
    oup = MSComm2.Input
    Text2.Text = oup
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
    MSComm1.CommPort = 3
    MSComm2.CommPort = 8
    MSComm1.PortOpen = True
    MSComm2.PortOpen = True
    MSComm1.Settings = "9600,n,8,1"
    MSComm2.Settings = "9600,n,8,1"
    MSComm2.RThreshold = 1
    'MSComm1.InputLen = 0
End Sub
```

Comment: I assume... you have a cable between the two ports ... and that it has the correct twist (or no twist)?

Comment: sir, these are the virtual ports... how would i connect them?

Comment: In what sense virtual?

Comment: SIR, i used two mscomm control but i saw some where they hv used only one mscomm ....And sir their is no comm port 3 and 8, fromwhere they will be connected